# How to use object instance of aubio.js in AudioWorklet / AudioWorkletProcessor

Tags: audio-worklet, audioworkletprocessor

My goal is to use the aubio.js methods in an AudioWorklet to have a better performance for pitch detection.

I tried to import the aubio.js library but because of its asynchronous nature, I was not successful to initiate the object.

Can anyone give me a hint? Maybe via AudioWorklet ports?